# play sound snappy ubuntu

Tags: sound, ubuntu-core

I am playing around with the latest Canonical AMI's on Amazon EC2. Does anyone know of a way to play a `.wav` file with Ubuntu-Snappy? Will docking one of the apps for Snappy implement some way of playing sound?

Answer (score 1):

Snappy install is not a Debian package manager but is like Google play and apple's App Store, if there is no app to deploy then somebody needs to make it. See how to create snappy apps for more details but the gist is to put your code and all its dependencies in a directory, add a meta subdirectory with a package.yaml and do snappy build directory. This will create a snap. Afterwards you test with snappy remote and finally you upload it to the store hence snappy install works.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you can do this via the terminal is via the `aplay` command.

You would simply run `aplay FILENAME.wav`.

Now, I'm not sure if Snappy core comes with that package, but if it doesn't, then you should be able to install it via `sudo snappy install alsa-base`. I will try and load up a snappy core image tomorrow and check to see.

I'm sure there are other methods, but `aplay` is definitely the simplest.

Comment: `code`ubuntu@localhost:~$ aplay test.wav
-bash: aplay: command not found
ubuntu@localhost:~$ apt-get aplay
Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snappy --help'!

Comment: @ralphieboy Did you try `sudo snappy install alsa-base`? Snappy core doesn't use `apt-get`

Comment: `ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install alsa-base`
`No package 'alsa-base' for ubuntu-core/devel`

Comment: @ralphieboy Hmm....I'm not sure then. I'll look around a bit and then get back to you as soon as I can.